# Struts2: multiple submit button

Tags: java, xml, jsp, struts2, form-submit

I would like to have 2 submit button in my jsp, so I found this tutorial: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html
I want to develop the Nyong Nyong's solution with MyBaseAction class, extended by MySubmitAction and MyClearAction class. But I can't get it work. 
I'm not sure how the jsp will be, this is in the example:

```
<s:form method="post" action="mySubmitAction">
    <s:submit value="Submit"/>
    <s:submit value="Clear" action="myClearAction"/>
</form>
```

But I suppose that it's referred to the previous example.
I'm not sure too about the struts.xml, do I need to set some specific constant value or other stuff?

Would be great if somebody could provide a full jsp and struts.xml example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using struts in a version **newer** than 2.3.15.2, you must add this constant to struts.xml to enable the `action:` prefix:

```xml
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```

because it has been disabled by default.

Read more on Security Bullettin [**S2-018**](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-018.html).

Comment: I lost one day, you're my hero! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the "names" of the actions to the actual Action classes you created. If you follow the example and have the struts.xml file like:

```
<action name="mySubmitAction" class="MySubmitAction">
       <result>submit.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="myClearAction" class="MyClearAction">
       <result>submit.jsp</result>
</action>
```

When you click on the input generated by `<s:submit value="Submit"/>` Struts2 will execute your `execute` method in your `MySubmitAction`. When you click on the input generated by `<s:submit value="Clear" action="myClearAction"/>` struts2 is supposed to override the default action specified by the `s:form` tag (I haven't tested it) and will execute the `execute` method in your `MyClearAction`.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is what is written in the guide. But I tried and doesn't work.
How will be the jsp? <s:form method="post" action="mySubmitAction">
Do I need to add some constant value or other stuff in the struts.xml

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any exception? The second button executes `mySubmitAction`?