# migrate struts version 2.3.1.2 to struts version 2.3.33 procedure

Tags: struts2

How to upgrade struts version?
I have found the below link but its not matching my requirement.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration

Comment: Read all versions notes between versions.

Comment: Not matching your requirements ? what requirements you have that is not covered on migration guide ?

Comment: @want2learn The guide is 2.3 to 2.5, their requirement is 2.3 to 2.3 :)

Comment: Shailendra, you probably need this before everything else: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21603806/1654265